# Print PDF from inside aspx page

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have an aspx page having a pdf shown inside it using a pdf viewer. the page is having textboxes above pdf document. I want to print this page with textboxes and pdf that is included inside it. is it possible? If yes can you please help me how?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Short answer iText.
You can save the pdf then print via Google cloud print. Pretty Slick

Comment: hi, thanks for your reply. can you give me a code example please.

Comment: i have used iTextSharp to display the pdf on page.. now i want to print it with textboxes values above it. is it possible?